# error in simple .getRange. function with multiple arguments

Tags: function, google-apps-script, arguments

**Hey Ppl.**
I've got a problem with my code :( (really?).
Maybe its dumb but i cant find any solution. 
I'm getting error on line 7. "
***TypeError: Can not call the "getRange" method of the null class.***
Internet, please help me!
~dying lame-developer

```js
function getPriceStand(poziom, pion,addr,sheet){

  //var adres = 'a1';
  //var skoroszyt = 'stand' 
  var adres = addr.toString(); // wprowadza pieprzone dane z zewnatrz
  var skoroszyt = sheet; 
  var c = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(skoroszyt).getRange(adres); //<<<<<
  var rowOffset = 1; 
  var columnOffset = 1;
  var ileKolumn = 0;
  var ileWierszy = 0;
  //
  while(c.offset(0,ileKolumn).getValue() != ''){ //sprawdzamy ile elementow poziom
    ileKolumn++;
    Logger.log('cena standu kolumna'+ileKolumn);
  }
  while(c.offset(ileWierszy,0).getValue() != ''){ //sprawdzamy ile elementow pion
    ileWierszy++;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < ileKolumn; i++ ){
    if (poziom >= c.offset(0,columnOffset).getValue()){
    columnOffset++;
    }}
  for (var i = 0; i < ileKolumn; i++ ){
    if (pion >= c.offset(rowOffset,0).getValue()){
    rowOffset++;
    }}
  
return(c.offset(rowOffset-1,columnOffset-1).getValue()); // wyrzucenie ceny z procedury
}
//var testCenyStandu = getPriceStand(300,800,'a1','stand'); // test values
//Logger.log('cena standu 300x800 :'+testCenyStandu);
```

Comment: I think that such error occurs when there is a problem at ``getSheetByName()``. So about ``skoroszyt`` you gave, the sheet name might be not existing in the active Spreadsheet. Can you confirm it again? If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: `var skoroszyt = sheet;` here sheet is equal to what ? If `sheet = 'stand' ;` then do you have sheet with the name `stand` case-sensitive ?

Comment: What are the object/literals used as the function arguments?